# Column Group Page Break

Tags: ssrs-2008

We have Matrix Report in Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 . We want Page break after every 50th column in Sql Server Reporting Services report 2005.

Thanks

Comment: Great!  What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure it's by column.. and not Row?